# Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found on xampp although soap is enabled

Tags: laravel, soap, xampp

I want to call a `soap` API in my project with `Laravel 8` and I get this error.

```
Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\API\app\Classes\tech.php on line 19
```

This is my code to call the webservice:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

class Tech
{
 private const URL = "...?wsdl";

    public function __construct()
        {
            try {
    
                $this->client = new \SoapClient(self::URL);
    
            } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    
                print_r("Getting Error When Connecting To WS" . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL);
    
            }
        }
}
```

And soap extension is enabled on `xampp`.

Comment: Did you uncomment `;extension=php_openssl.dll`?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't commented.